# Jquery: Validate Form without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, validation

I need help in validating my contact form using jquery. I am following an example that is from youtube  h[ttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wUu7pWBygY&feature=relmfu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wUu7pWBygY&feature=relmfu)

Though it works for me using only a single field but however , if want to add a field to validate using the solution, it does't work anymore.

Here's my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

            $(document).ready(function() {
                //$('.error-div').load('action/validate_signup.php').show();

                $('#fname').keyup(function() {
                    $.post('action/validate_signup.php', { fname: form.fname.value }, 
                    function(result){
                        $('#fname-error').html(result).show("slow");
                    });

                });


                $('#lname').keyup(function() {
                    $.post('action/validate_signup.php', { lname: form.lname.value }, 
                    function(result){
                        $('#lname-error').html(result).show("slow");
                    });

                });
            });

        </script>
```

and this is my validation process suppose to be:

```
<?php

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];

    if(empty($fname)){
        echo " *First Name Required";   
    }elseif(strlen($fname)<=3){
        echo "*Name too short!";
    }else{
        echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
    }

    if(empty($lname)){
        echo " *Last Name Required";    
    }elseif(strlen($lname)<=3){
        echo "*Lastname too short!";
    }else{
        echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
    }



?>
```

Please help, thanks in advance and more power

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you either provide `fname` or `lname` to the validation script, but not both. Your validation script will always return an error.

I recommend using the [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to check whether `fname` or `lname` is supplied to the script at all, before checking them with `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Using client side validation looks like a better idea here. As you put the jquery tag, how about using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation ?

Comment: Client side validation would make for a better user experience in this case, but he will still need the validation on the server as well to ensure that the submitted data is valid.

Comment: I would agree if that was email or username uniqueness validation but just for length or if fields are required? I would do that check after post just before saving to the database.

Comment: Please don't mind about the string length validation :-), i just put it there something to have something to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Since they're both using the same kind of validation(checking if length is greater than 3) just use a single function to check for it. Also use html5 to make the field required, so that it won't be submitted to the server unless its filled out.

html:

```
<input type="text" id="lname" required/>
```

script:

```
$('#lname').keyup(function(){
  var lname = $.trim($(this).val());
  $.post('check.php', {'value' : lname}, function(data){
    $('#lname-error').html(result).show("slow");
  });
});
```

And here's check.php:

```
$valid = check_length($_POST['value']);
echo $valid;

function check_length($str){
   $clean_string = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
   if(str_len($clean_string ) <= 3){
      //return error message
   }else{
      //return check mark
   }
}
```